# How to setup UITableViewCell imageView with image got from the server - double request

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I'm wondering what is the best way to set images in my `UITableView` from the server. I'm storing images on the amazon s3 and to get images I have implemented logic in the backend that require two statements:

- first one I'm using to get url of image and in the second one I just simply display images to the `UITableViewCell`. For web requests I'm using AFNetworking library and addition to UIImageView `(<UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>)`. I don't have a problem with requests, however I'm not quite sure where should I put my code responsible for getting all urls of the images. It seems to me that `cellForARowAtIndexPath` method is good only for displaying images from the final url address:

Here is my code.

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"final url here"]];
 [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GeofencingAlert.png"] 
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage
 *image) 
 {

 } 
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
 }];
```

Should I first download all of the url stored on the amazon s3 and put them into the NSMutuableArray ?  If yes what is the best way to execute multiple requests? What if the user add new record to the table ? Do I have to execute multiple requests again to keep my UITableVIewCell images updated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-(void)viewDidLoad` method. Something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   urlPaths = nil;
   [httpClient loadUrlsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *results){
      urlPaths = results; // urlPaths - class member
      [tableView reloadData];
   }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
  //...
  if(urlPaths)
  {
    NSString *urlPath = urlPaths[indexPath.row];
    // load async
  }
  else
  // urls are not loaded yet
    imageView.image = placeholderImage;
}
```